# How do I backup my file system with tar and multi-thread?

Tags: backup, tar, multi-core

I would like to backup my file system and do it with parallel. I found this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR
Where they give me the command:

```
tar -cvpzf backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz --one-file-system /
```

I found that I should put `-I pigz` in the beginning of the command, however this gives me the error:

```
tar: Conflicting compression options
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: With the modification, it's your conflicting command looks like this: `tar -I pigz -cvpzf backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz --one-file-system /` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `z` flag you have in your command means:

```
   -z, --gzip, --gunzip, --ungzip
          Filter the archive through gzip(1).
```

So if you then use `-I` which means:

```
  -I, --use-compress-program=COMMAND
        Filter data through COMMAND.  It must accept the  -d  option,  for  decompression.
        The argument can contain command line options.
```

Then you are telling it to use both `gzip` and `pigz`, so it complains because you've given it conflicting compression options. So just remove the `z`:

```
tar -cvf backup.tar.gz -I pigz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz --one-file-system /
```

Note that I also removed the `-p` since that shouldn't have any effect when creating an archive:

```
  -p, --preserve-permissions, --same-permissions
          extract information about file permissions (default for superuser)
```

You should use that when extracting, not when creating the archive.